# Android dynamically stacking views

Tags: android

It seems that this issue is pretty confusing to me.

I just want a view to be added on click on top of another one. Something like this:

- View
- View
- View
- View

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on what "on top of another one" means.

If you mean on the Y axis (vertically up the screen), use a `vertical` `LinearLayout`.

If you mean on the Z axis (perpendicular to the screen, heading towards the user's eyes), use a `FrameLayout` or `RelativeLayout`, where later children are higher on the Z axis than are earlier children. Or, if your `minSdkVersion` is 21 or higher, you can use the `elevation` property to control the Z axis positioning.